# How to count how many times each value appear

Tags: excel

If I have an line like:

> 15, 15, 9, 10

How can I count how many times each value appeared? In this example, it would be like:

> 15: 2, 9: 1, 10: 1

or

> 15: 50%, 9: 25%, 10: 25%

I don't know if it can help, but my intended use case is to check the most common openings in a chess game, and the distribution. For that, I have an set with 20041 games, each one with an value like D10, B00, C20, C50...

Comment: You can find the answer on the superuser SE site.
https://superuser.com/questions/1297192/count-with-grouping-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily with COUNTIF (use it to count specific value) and COUNTA(to count all non empty)

[image]

> [COUNTA
>   Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/counta-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
>
> [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)

The formula I've used in A2 is:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$1;A1)/COUNTA($A$1:$D$1)
```

And then applied % format.

In case you want only to count how many times each value appear, just do:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$D$1;A1)
```

And normal format.

[image]

Hope this helps